# Why does QML Menu not close on outside press when given an id on a QQuickWidget?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a `ComboBox` with a custom `Menu` popup which is rendered on a `QQuickWidget`. When the `Menu` is given an `id` property, I can't seem to make it close on press outside, no matter what `closePolicy` I set.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ComboBox {
    popup: Menu {
        id: menu    //comment this line and menu will behave normally
//        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnPressOutside  //this doesn't seem to have any effect
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QQuickWidget *quickWidget = new QQuickWidget;
    quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    quickWidget->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I have tested on Qt 5.14.2 and 5.13.1 MSVC2017. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#avoid-assigning-an-id-to-styles-implementations-of-item-delegates) do actually suggest avoiding giving an `id` to styles of controls, but not for this reason.

Comment: @JarMan noted, thanks for the insight